# What is the difference between UICollectionViewCell and UICollectionReusableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Looking through UICollectionView tutorials, I see some where `UICollectionViewCell` is subclassed for items, and some where `UICollectionReusableView` is subclassed instead. The docs don't make it very clear when you would use one over the other.

Comment: It's worth noting that `UICollectionViewCell` is a subclass of `UICollectionReusableView`

Answer (score 12):

**UICollectionViewCell**

> A UICollectionViewCell object presents the content for a single data
>   item when that item is within the collection view’s visible bounds.
>   You can use this class as-is or subclass it to add additional
>   properties and methods. The layout and presentation of cells is
>   managed by the collection view and its corresponding layout object.

**UICollectionReusableView**

> The UICollectionReusableView class defines the behavior for all cells
>   and supplementary views presented by a collection view. Reusable views
>   are so named because the collection view places them on a reuse queue
>   rather than deleting them when they are scrolled out of the visible
>   bounds. Such a view can then be retrieved and repurposed for a
>   different set of content.

So the difference is that a `UICollectionViewCell` presents the content for a single data item and a `UICollectionReusableView`  class defines the behavior for all cells and supplementary views presented by a collection view.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Apple recommends that you use `UICollectionViewCell` both for cells and for supplementary views. That way, you get the useful features such as the background view. `UICollectionReusableView` is merely what makes these views reusable. So there is no important distinction except for the built-in superclass–subclass relationship.

Comment: Do you have a source for Apple's recommendation?

Comment: @shim Yes, they told me directly.

Comment: @matt Hahaha nice!!